# Finding average?

Tags: python, sum, average

I am new to python, and I wondered if anyone could help me find the average in the following marks list of students?. Please advise as to what I am doing wrong here.

```
student_marks = [['Name',  ['A','B','C','D','E']],
                 ['Ankit',  [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Aravind',[42, 23, 34, 44, 53]],
                 ['Lakshay',[32, 23, 13, 54, 67]],
                 ['Gyan',   [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Pranav', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]

for student in student_marks[1:]:
    marks_in_C = student[1][2]
    
    print(marks_in_C, end=" ")

total = sum(marks_in_C)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What result did you expect and what did you get? When you printed `marks_in_C`, what did it show? Was it what you expected?

Comment: It's not really clear from your code what you are trying to average. Do you just want to print the average of each row?

Comment: It seems like you want to get the average of the students along the column `C`. Add `marks_in_C = []` before the loop and replace `marks_in_C = student[1][2]` with `marks_in_C.append(student[1][2])`. If you want the average, put `avg = total / len(marks_in_C)` at the end.

Comment: Use the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#module-statistics) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the average of **C** in this two ways:

```py
student_marks = [['Name',  ['A','B','C','D','E']],
                 ['Ankit',  [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Aravind',[42, 23, 34, 44, 53]],
                 ['Lakshay',[32, 23, 13, 54, 67]],
                 ['Gyan',   [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Pranav', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]
                
total_C = 0

for [name, [A, B, C, D, E]] in student_marks[1:]:
    total_C += C
    
avg_of_C = total_C / len(student_marks[1:])
print(avg_of_C)
```

**OR**

```py
student_marks = [['Name',  ['A','B','C','D','E']],
                 ['Ankit',  [41, 34, 45, 55, 63]],
                 ['Aravind',[42, 23, 34, 44, 53]],
                 ['Lakshay',[32, 23, 13, 54, 67]],
                 ['Gyan',   [23, 82, 23, 63, 34]],
                 ['Pranav', [21, 23, 25, 56, 56]]
                ]
                
marks_in_C = list()

for [name, [A, B, C, D, E]] in student_marks[1:]:
    marks_in_C.append(C)

avg_of_C = sum(marks_in_C) / len(marks_in_C)
print(avg_of_C)
```

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to **Python** world! The error occurred because you are using **int** type data to be iterated. `sum()` method expect iterable data but `marks_in_C` has only one integer which cannot be iterated

I think you are trying to use `marks_in_C` as a list. why don't you use your loop looks like this?

```py
...
marks_in_C = list()

for student in student_marks[1:]:
    marks_in_C.append(student[1][2])
    
    print(marks_in_C, end=" ")

total = sum(marks_in_C)
```

hope it to help you.